# Paladins - The screen is showing up black

Tags: paladins

My computer is more than capable of running Paladins graphics on maximum, and I have before, but now every time I run the game and play it, the screen goes black except for the ui/hud, I also can't see characters when I look at them from the main menu. I've also messed around with the graphic settings and it didn't change anything. Somebody please help, and any help/suggestions are appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at several threads about this on the official paladins forum :

- A pinned post by admin : [Black Screen issues: PLEASE READ IF THIS HAPPENS TO YOU](http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?22774-Black-Screen-issues-PLEASE-READ-IF-THIS-HAPPENS-TO-YOU)
- [Black screen in game](http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?22298-Black-screen-in-game)
- [I can't see anything in game](http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?21882-I-cant-see-anything-in-game)
- [Black screen, I can see only the GUI](http://forums.paladins.com/showthread.php?22386-Black-screen-I-can-see-only-the-GUI)

Here is the main solution that seems to works for most people :

> PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY *'ChaosSystemSettings'* or you will be highly at risk for this issue!
>
> Do this to resolve the issue:
>   On the **Launcher** > Click on the **gear icon** at bottom-left > Click **Clear Game Settings**.